# Calculation between two Frangments in an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to calculate each item separately as well as together. Also want to print the Quantity. Now I'm only able to print Total Amount. But i have to insert value in each Item. If I leave 1 blank the app crashes.

Image 1 is the `FrangmentActivity` showing calculating Total Amount

[image: image 1]

Image 2 is crashing of the app when i leave 1 blank input and tried to calculate

[image: image 2]

**TopSectionFragment**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment {

private static EditText editText2, editText3, editText4;

TopSectionListener activityCommander;

public interface TopSectionListener {
    public void createQuantity(String result);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, 
container, false);


    editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQSmall);
    editText3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQMedium);
    editText4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etQLarge);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCal);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClicked(v);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
public void buttonClicked(View view){

    int smallPizza = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    int mediumPizza = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    int largePizza = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().toString());

    //Do Calculation Small = 15, Medium = 20, Large = 25

    int total = (smallPizza * 15) + (mediumPizza * 20) + (largePizza * 
    25);

    String result = "Total RM "+total;
    activityCommander.createQuantity(result);
   }
}
```

**BottomSectionFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class BottomSectionFragment extends Fragment{

private static TextView textAmount;
private static TextView textQuantity;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_section_fragment, 
container, false);

    textAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
    textQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);

    return view;
}
public void setText(String amount){
    textAmount.setText(amount);
 }
}
```

FragmentActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TopSectionFragment.TopSectionListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
}

@Override
public void createQuantity(String amount) {
    BottomSectionFragment bottomFragment = (BottomSectionFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    bottomFragment.setText(amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can You please add your log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `textbox` is **empty** or not before converting inside `onClick()`

```
int smallPizza, mediumPizza ,largePizza;
if(!editText1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
   smallPizza = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
}else{
   smallPizza = 0;
}
if(!editText2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
   mediumPizza = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
}else{
   mediumPizza = 0;
}
if(!editText3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
   largePizza = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
}else{
   largePizza = 0;
}

int total = (smallPizza * 15) + (mediumPizza * 20) + (largePizza * 25);
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother, it worked. can u please tell me how i can i print the quantity as well.

Comment: where you want to print the quantity?

Comment: If u can see the picture there is TextView calling Quantity. its in BottomSectionFragment.

Comment: Set that similar like you set the Total amount